# Primefaces dialog overlay not working

Tags: javascript, jsf, tomcat, primefaces, overlay

Googled before posting. Did not found up-to-date information. Last problem recorded back in 2011, which suggested to use appendTo in the css considering the answer was based on the version of primefaces in 2011, I checking the documentation on the showcase and did not found anything regarding that. Made a blank .xhtml to check if something is wrong with primefaces or my code. Surprise, it works fine on the blank .xhtml just copied everything in the show case. (url: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml ) use the Modal example, you can find it at the end of the code. Simple copy paste does not seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <link href="css/imgareaselect-animated.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function preview(img, selection)
            {   
                if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
                    return;

                $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
                $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
                $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
                $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
                $('#w').val(selection.width);
                $('#h').val(selection.height);    
            }

            $(function ()
            {
                $('#photo').imgAreaSelect(
                {      
                    onSelectChange: preview
                });
            });

            function teste() {
                alert( document.getElementById('x1').value );
            }
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="title">
            <p:outputLabel>Psiengine interactive office</p:outputLabel>
        </div>
        <form action="index3.html" onsubmit="teste()" method="post">
            <div>
                <img id="photo" src="images/office.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <table style="margin-top: 1em;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" style="font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 0.1em;">
                                Coordinates
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2" style="font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 0.1em;">
                                Dimensions
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 10%;">
                                <b>X<sub>1</sub>:
                                </b>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 30%;"><input type="text" id="x1" value="-" /></td>
                            <td style="width: 20%;"><b>Width:</b></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="-" id="w" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Y<sub>1</sub>:
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="y1" value="-" /></td>
                        <td><b>Height:</b></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="h" value="-" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>X<sub>2</sub>:
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="x2" value="-" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Y<sub>2</sub>:
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="y2" value="-" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                <p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
                <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
            </p:dialog>   
        </form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied your code in my Primefaces project (Primefaces 4.0). The modal dialog have no issue. (I didn't used your code from `<h:head />` because there were some errors and you don't need that code to trigger the modal).

Hint:
When you use an `<p:dialog modal="true" />` without an "appendTo" attribute in a `<p:layout />` component you will get an overlay issue (the overlay will come in front of the dialog panel).
I saw that Primefaces adds `z-index: 0` to `<p:layoutUnit />` so if you set the `z-index` to `auto` for `.ui-layout-unit` the overlay is displayed ok.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to create a template with ui:insert and ui:composition using p:layout. But I had this issue and put the p:dialog outside the layout wasn't an alternative for me. Googling, I've noticed many people have had this issue since many years ago and always the answer was the same, I mean, to put the dialog outside. Your answer has saved my day, putting z-index: auto !important to overwrite the style of .ui-layout-unit has worked like a charm.