# In angular 12 with bootstrap 5 with ngPrime i need to overlap a p-dialog of any other element that i have

Tags: css, angular, modal-dialog, primeng, z-index

In angular 12 with bootstrap 5 with ngPrime i need to overlap a p-dialog of any other element that i have, how do i do this whitout use z-index and css just with primeng?

I alredy used z-index with

```
.my-class{
    z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

but I heven't good, so i need a way to overlap my refresh modal on the others modals

```
<p-dialog
  [visible]="display"
  [modal]="true"
  [transitionOptions]="'10ms'"
  class="auto-refresh"`your text`
  [closeOnEscape]="false"
  [closable]="false"
  [focusOnShow]="false"
>
```

that is my p-dialog tests i do not have any good result

Answer (score 0):

when we use <p:dialog modal="true" /> without an "appendTo" attribute in a <p:layout /> component you will get an overlay issue (the overlay will come in front of the dialog panel). I saw that Primefaces adds z-index: 0 to <p:layoutUnit /> so if you set the z-index to auto for .ui-layout-unit the overlay is displayed ok.

here is example
[Primefaces dialog overlay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627637/primefaces-dialog-overlay-not-working)

Comment: Thancks that helps!, but the solutions is that i had to disable the autoZindex and put the position relative (to get the childs elements)